# How to print Shell command literally?

Tags: shell

In a shell script, is there a way to print command in this literal form after all variables are replaced with real value. For example, `mkdir -p $HOME/src`, before this command is executed, print something like `mkdir -p /home/user/src`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `set -x` argument and check [this](http://www.faqs.org/docs/abs/HTML/options.html)